# Cannot capture image through a USB webcam connected to Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-4

So I connected a usb webcam to my RPi 4, installed fswebcam and tried to take a picture with the command `fswebcam 1.jpg` but it shows the following error [image: error] Can anyone please provide a solution to this? I have tried rebooting the pi and also connecting the camera at other usb ports but still the problem remains the same.

Comment: It looks like a permissions problem.  You need to edit your question and tell us what permissions the Pi user has and what permissions are shown for /dev/video0.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo fswebcam 1.jpg`?

Comment: add pi user to the video group via: sudo usermod -a -G video pi

Comment: @joan I do not know hot to do that. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Abel I tried it but the error still persists.

Comment: @MatsKarlsson yes I tried that also but the problem still persists.

Comment: sometimes a camera will show up as multiple.  try a different # such as /dev/video0, /dev/video1, etc.  I've found webcamoid to be helpful in debugging camera settings as not all cameras support all formats/resolutions.